# Argument is passed to function

Tags: c, linux

Consider the following sources:
main.c

```
int main(){
    print_hello("str");
    return 0;
}
```

and hello.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void print_hello(){
    printf("Hello world\n");
}
```

After compiling and linking `gcc -o hello hello.c main.c` it's work fine, but I'm expected that error will be occured. Because signatures of `print_hello` in `main.c` and `print_hello` in `hello.c` are differents. Why it works fine?

Comment: Try `-Wall` option while compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler uses [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) which allows extra arguments passing to called function without extra effects. This is typical between calling conventions for C, due to its support of variable argument lists (as in printf, scanf, etc.) In such conventions,

- arguments are passed in the order that the first argument is the closest to the stack top (if all are placed on stack) or in a equivalent register, and others are put in sequence,
- caller knows used stack size and restores stack pointer after function call.

In [X86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) this is usually named "cdecl" (optionally, with 1 or 2 underscores).

A such convention is tolerable to extra arguments, but, definitely, not to unspecified arguments which are then used by a callee function; the latter case results in garbage in arguments.

Generally one shouldn't exploit such runtime features, but there are some corner cases it's useful.

To prevent mismatch between a function use and its definition, you should use identical declarations for both. Typically it's done including the same header file to all sources where this function is declared or called.

Comment: Thanks for this exhaustive answer! Please give me a link to a `C` standard clause about this conventions.

Comment: I can't give you a link to conventions in C standard due to their absense. C standard is designed for much wider conditions than register machines, stack based machines, etc., and the only thing it specifies that, if a function declaration is provided to all sources which use it, no weird effects will appear. All convention details are platform specific, despite most of them are similar in principles.

Answer (score 1):

You've not told the compiler about what the `print_hello()` function looks like in the file `main.c`.  If you had a header file `hello.h` such as:

```
#ifndef HELLO_H_INCLUDED
#define HELLO_H_INCLUDED

extern void print_hello(void);

#endif
```

And you had `#include "hello.h"` at the top of each file, then you'd get the relevant compiler warnings from misusing `print_hello()` in `main.c`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other explanations, assuming [GCC 4.8](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/) or better on Linux :

You should compile with `gcc -Wall -std=c99` to get all warnings (`-Wall`) and to tell the compiler which standard you want to obey (`-std=c99`). With these settings you get warned:

```
  main.c: In function 'main':
  main.c:2:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'print_hello' 
              [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  print_hello("str");
 ^
```

As to why no errors are given, they could be given only at [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) time by the linker (`ld`, called by `gcc`). And Unix and Linux linkers (from GNU [binutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/)) work only with names: each function (and more generally each linked symbol) has a name (and both object files and executables are in [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), which defines how names are represented, etc....) If two names are the same the linker resolves by making them refer to the same address (see [Linkers and Loaders](http://www.iecc.com/linker/) by Levine). So since both names (or symbols) in `main.o` and `hello.o` are `print_hello` they are linked together. Use [`nm`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.24/binutils/nm.html#nm) to query the names in an ELF object or executable file. Of course, what happens then at runtime is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), but the [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) conventions for [x86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) (and [x86-64](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf%E2%80%8E)) enable the behavior you expect. The important thing is that ELF do not keep typing or signature meta-data in object files.

With C++, it is a bit different: the compiler is transforming a function name by [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) (so names in ELF `*.o` files are not simply the C++ source name), so the linker sees different names (and would have failed).